# hover is not working on child element

Tags: html, css

I have div inside a div as below

```
<div id="locations">
    <div id="h-dragbar"></div>
</div>
```

and css as below

```
#locations {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

#h-dragbar{
   background-color:black;
   width:100%;
   height: 3px;
   position: absolute;
   cursor: row-resize;
   bottom: 0;       
   z-index: 999;
}

#h-dragbar:hover{
   background-color:blue;
}
```

but hover on div with id **h-dragbar** is not working. You can test the code here [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9nz2nwa/).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The jsFiddle works perfectly for me.

Comment: What's your browser ?

Comment: Works just fine, you just have 3px of hover area though

Comment: Sorry. I put wrong link. I have updated it. You can check it again.

Comment: You have a negative zindex on the container element, what did you expect, right click and inspect....

Comment: Actually this works: http://jsfiddle.net/zr4mt3mk/

Comment: I have checked it. I need to set z-index to -1 to access the one outer div.

Comment: @Sanky The outer div is above what you are trying to hover.....

Comment: So show us ALL your code that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new example jsFiddle which you've provided, you're setting a `z-index` of `-1` to the parent div i.e. `#locations` which is why you're unable to perform the hover function on its child div i.e. `#h-dragbar`. You will need to remove the negative `z-index` on `#locations` and then it'll work fine.

Update:

I've checked your latest fiddle and instead of using a negative `z-index` for `#locations` in order to give priority to `#v-dragbar`, you can achieve the same by using a high `z-index` for `#v-dragbar`, for e.g. `z-index: 9999`, and a relatively smaller `z-index` for `#locations`, for e.g. `z-index: 9998`. It'll work perfectly this way. Here's a demo:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#explorer {
  width: 13%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#v-dragbar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  width: 2px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}
#h-dragbar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: row-resize;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
#h-dragbar:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
#v-dragbar:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
#locations {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9998;
  /*imp*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="explorer">
    <div id="v-dragbar"></div>
    <span style="clear: both;"></span>
    <div id="locations">
      <div id="h-dragbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="datapoints">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="explorer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need z-index to be -1 for other purpose.

Comment: @Sanky What's the other purpose?

Comment: Check this, it works perfectly as per your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/p9nz2nwa/1/ @sanky

Comment: @Sanky Great! I've also updated my answer above with an explanation which you can read. You can mark my answer as correct since it has solved your query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because of the negative z-index - you're basically putting the whole thing behind the body element, rendering it non-hoverable, non-clickable, etc. We can't help further without more context, but you'll need to change your strategy a bit for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot make a positive `z-index`, make a `z-index: 0;` and check. It works:

```css
#locations {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#h-dragbar{
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: row-resize;
  bottom: 0;    
  z-index: 999;
}

#h-dragbar:hover{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="locations">
  <div id="h-dragbar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine…

However, try:

```
#h-dragbar:hover{
   background-color:blue !important;
}
```

If now it works, for you, it means that some other CSS instance has priority.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted - Carles is offering a test to help the OP determine if specificity is the issue or not: "If now it works, for you, it means that some other CSS instance has priority."

Comment: Seems unlikely that a specific ID like that would lose in **priority**. It may have been overriden later in the stylesheet though.

Comment: This "answer" depends on some very heavy speculation about code that doesn't appear in the question.

Comment: Actually, now that I've viewed the demo, it appears the answerer didn't (view the demo).

Comment: @ShawnErquhart I answered based on the previous link ;-)

Comment: Peace, not war. Have fun.

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda I saw the original - there were only a few rules, so specificity wasn't really an issue. I still think the downvote pile is unwarranted.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart People don't paste their entire CSS files in a SO question, do they? `!important` has helped me a lot of times to discover that it was a CSS priority issue. Nevermind.

Comment: You are right, jumped to conclusions way to fast, apologies.

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda read my comments, I've defended your answer against the downvote vultures with each one. My last comment was simply addressing your assumption that I viewed the wrong code.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Sorry! Yes, I didn't see you were the same person.